# Intro. analysis - proof that $x \in N_{\epsilon}a$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Define: $$N_{\epsilon}a=\{x: |x-a|< \epsilon\}$$

Show that if $\epsilon$>0 and $|x-a|<\epsilon$ then $x \in N_{\epsilon}a$

I first note that $N_{\epsilon}a =(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$

then I consider three cases:

**1. $x=a$.** we are done.

**2. $x>a$**

$|x-a|=|\alpha x|<\epsilon$ where $\alpha \in (0,1]$
$\to$ $\alpha x<\epsilon$ $\to$ $x<\epsilon+a$

this shows $a<x<\epsilon+a$ $\implies$ $x\in N_{\epsilon}a$

**3. $x<a$:**

$|x-a|=|-\alpha a|$ where $\alpha \in (0,1]$ $\to$ $-(-\alpha a)<\epsilon$
$\to$ $(-\alpha a)>-\epsilon$ $\to$ $x>a-\epsilon$

This shows that $a-\epsilon<x<a$ $\implies$ $X \in N_{\epsilon}a$

---

Is this okay for a rough draft of this? Anyone see anything I need to fix?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if $|x-a|<\epsilon$ then isn't $x\in N_\epsilon a$ by definition?

Comment: I don't think that you are. I thought the exact same thing when given this problem today. So i just tried to rephrase it into what you see here.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with your working then, the question is trivial.